# How to get linebreak location from DOM element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

In my HTML page, I have long text that has some auto-generated linebreaks at certain words (using `line-break: normal`), now a JavaScript library ([vue-typer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-typer)) types the same text but does line breaks at certain characters and doesn't support breaking the text at words.

So I wanted to fetch all linebreaks locations from the default HTML text and insert them into the vue-typer string so it will do line breaks at the same place.

So the question becomes: How to get the location of a linebreak from a DOM text?

Comment: Why would you want that? Do you have a client that's gonna be mad if you can't get the exact same line-breaks?

Comment: @AndreNuechter I use the first div (with `line-break: normal`) to calculate the height and I want it to match the vue-typer result, and I could of course, line-break at a character but I think it's pretty bad for readability if you line-break mid-word

Comment: Why do you want to match the result? I personally think proper word-breaking increases readability. I'd suggest you have a look at [word-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap).

Comment: So you prefer breaking the sentence at a letter instead of at a space? I'm just making sure we're on the same page. The problem is vue-typer places every letter in a div which causes the line-breaks in the middle of word, so I can't use word-wrap (I think).

Comment: I prefer to not think too much about this and have the browser handle that. But if all you get is a series of divs each with a letter, then you indeed cant use word-wrap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Idea:** Identify each line with its **`Y-position`**.

Here is a simple algorithm, I followed**^**

- wrap up each word with an element, in order to use JS.
- then, apply `.offsetTop` property on each word to get its `Y-position`.
- now, loop up on every element and group them based on their `Y-position`, i.e., extract lines.
- lastly, the position of line-breaks are simply the *"end of each line"*, hence it is `line.length`

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p');
p.innerHTML = '<span>' + p.innerHTML.split(' ').join(' </span><span>') + '</span>'; // add spans in b/w

let spans = [...p.querySelectorAll('span')];
let initY = spans[0].offsetTop; // get the offsetTop for first line

let lines = [''], idx = 0, i; 
for(i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  if(spans[i].offsetTop - initY > 2) {
    initY = spans[i].offsetTop; // reset the Y
    lines.push(''); // add starting of line
    idx++; // move to next line
  }
  lines[idx] += spans[i].innerText; // add the text everytime
}

let breaks = lines.map((val, idx) => [idx, val.length]);
// ^ get (row, col) pairs
console.log(breaks);
```

```css
p {
  line-break: normal;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum felis elit, scelerisque id rhoncus et, hendrerit nec turpis. Phasellus eget condimentum justo. Aliquam porta, risus sed elementum hendrerit, turpis urna posuere libero, eget facilisis sem purus sed mi. Nulla pulvinar nibh quis bibendum lacinia. Aenean eu nibh pharetra, imperdiet mi eget, vehicula mauris. In hac    habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus ante enim, bibendum quis turpis a, volutpat auctor mi. Mauris scelerisque sem a ornare dignissim. Nullam in sem ac turpis aliquet dictum sit amet dignissim est.</p>
```

**^**: Many thanks to user GetSet, who helped me in developing the idea :)

Comment: Ahahah, thank you! These aren't the types of problems I'm used to dealing with but thank you for coming up with such a creative solution ;)

Comment: Hey @Schotsl, can you share your problem more clearly, as I thought my answer was legal.

Comment: I'm sorry your answer was correct, I'd already given the bounty to you but forgot to mark it as the answer, thank you very much :)

Comment: It's okay @Schotsl, I'm glad I could help you. Thanks for your appreciations :)